# Play with kubernetes not exposing the node port to outside world

Tags: docker, kubernetes

While creating service with node port in Play with kubernetes its not exposing the url to access the service

I think its happening very frequently now, does any one facing this issue?

Comment: What environment are you running in? GKE, AKS, OnPrem? What URL would you like to have exposed?

Comment: its play with kubernetes.  I am exposing the basic nginx deployment with NodePort

Answer (score 1):

NodePort never "exposes URL". NodePort is only creating a specific forwarding/nat rules to make sure trafic from port X on all nodes running kube-proxy is "redirected" to endpoints of service Y.

Comment: yes, but this is specific to Play with Kubernetes. where we can expose the service as Nodeport and it will expose the links to outside network